# Social Login doesn't work in Android browser app

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login, sharetribe

I have a question regarding social login for horsedeal24.com. We're using Sharetribe Flex as API solution for our marketplace app and just configured social login. We relied on these documentations:

Google: https://www.sharetribe.com/docs/cookbook-social-logins-and-sso/enable-google-login/
Facebook: https://www.sharetribe.com/docs/cookbook-social-logins-and-sso/enable-facebook-login/

We now noticed that users can't login if they use our android browser app - it seems that our app does not have permission yet for OAuth (see screenshots) but we also don't know how to grant access.

Google Error: 403:disallowed_useragent
Facebook Error: For your account security, logging into Facebook from an embedded browser is disabled.

Here you can download our beta version of our android app to reproduce the issue. Simply try to create an account by using social login.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best regards,
Beni

[Google & Facebook Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r0JY.png)[Facebook App Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xIgQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Facebook Login is disabled if you try to open from inside a `WebView` in an Android device.

[image]

> For your account security, logging into Facebook from an embedded
> browser is disabled. To continue, download and log into the Facebook
> app on your device and try again.

The solution must be implement the native Facebook Login with the Facebook SDK for android

[**Facebook Login for Android - Quickstart**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)

or just open your login form in the mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is most likely because of you are not using the latest facebook login sdk version which is 8.2 .

follow the instructions in
[this article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews)